# How to increment and show the number of form after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to increment the form number once the user had submitted the form successfully. Is there any way to increment it through JavaScript or jQuery.

```html
<form action="">
  form no:1<br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value ="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <button type="submit" onclick="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jyotirawat/7ysk905c/ here is the example

Comment: Please **[edit]** your original question and add code in it. Links are okay, but only if they accompany the basic code.. :)

Comment: Is the form actually *submitted*? Or do you send it via ajax?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder There is no ajax call. It's a google form integrated in html and css by taking the data-entery

Comment: @JyotiRawat The question is, where are you submitting the contents of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("form").submit(function () {
    $.post("url", $(this).serialize(), function () {
      $("#count").text(parseInt($("#count").text() + 1);
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  form no: <span id="count">1</span><br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value ="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <button type="submit" onclick="increment();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: but in this case the values which the user enters will be reset right the form wont get submitted

Comment: hi praveen, instead of calling through a function is their any other way? Because I am this form as google form where the values will be saved in excel sheet after submitting and I have already put onclick function in submit button.

Comment: @Manish I know. The question was to increment the count. The OP can choose to fire an AJAX call on submission as well.

Comment: @JyotiRawat We need to see the full code and the context to understand what you are trying to achieve. So, in your `onclick` function, you can add the increment function too.

Comment: @JyotiRawat As said by Manish, this will not submit the data. In reality, you might need either an AJAX Call or a server to handle the POST method.

Comment: @JyotiRawat Sorry didn't notice you have added [tag:jquery] as well. Updating the answer. Give me a moment.

Comment: @Praveen you used reset thats why i pointed this out because in the question she has mentioned when the form is submitted successfully.

Comment: @Manish I didn't blame you. BTW, see my updated answer. That exactly answers the question. Doesn't it? The form count gets incremented only when the AJAX call succeeds.

Comment: @JyotiRawat That was a pseudo code. You need to tell where you wanna post it, so that ... Update the `"url"` there to post it right. But I don't understand how you got that error message. Kindly share your full code and screenshot of the error message?